# Is it valid to use std::function with incomplete types?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I wondered if it is valid to use `std::function` with incomplete type, e.g. in case of forward declaration. I wrote this small code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct S;

std::function<S(void)> m;

struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n";}
};

S goo() {
    return S{};
}

int main() {
    m = goo;
    m().foo();
}
```

Even though the `S` is incomplete in the point of declaring `m`, I could declare return type like a complete type(a non-pointer return type). This code complies and works correctly, but I'm not sure if this code is valid by standard. Because you cannot forward declare return type if it is not a pointer in a normal function(so I cannot forward declare `S` for `goo()`).

Any idea if this is a valid code by standard or not?

Comment: I suspect so always although I'm the opposite of a language lawyer. It's essential for the generality of `std::function` to be able function largely without a complete definition of the function or function object it works with except when it's constructed. The ctor needs the complete definition to capture it. Everywhere else shouldn't (dtor, `operator()`, copy ctor, assignment operator, etc) or else it would be near useless.

Comment: You can think of it similarly to how a function pointer doesn't (and shouldn't) require a complete definition to point to a function. It only needs its signature and return type. That said, I am talking about how things *should* work (and how they work for me all compilers I've tested). I am not sure about how things *do* work, but I can at least point out that they should work this way to be usable.

Comment: Could be me but I do not see an "incomplete type", S is declared and all its methods are defined, `m` will be using global function `goo` (also defined).  The only thing is that there is no instance of S at line `m=goo()` which has nothing to do with an incomplete type. Then calling `m()` will return an  instance of S, on which you will call foo().
I don't consider myself a language laywer either (but using C++ for almost 30 years) but all in all I think there is nothing language laywer going on here. Just straightforward C++ doing its thing.

Comment: *"Because you cannot forward declare return type if it is not a pointer in a normal function(so I cannot forward declare S for goo())."* -- not exactly true. While an incomplete type cannot be the return type for a function definition, it can be used in a function **declaration** (e.g. `S goo();` is legal when `S` is incomplete). Since you are discussing types, a function's declaration seems more apropos than its definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea if this is a valid code by standard or not?

The program is **well-formed** because even though `S` is incomplete at the point of the definition `std::function<S(void)> m;`, the `std::function` doesn't place any requirement on `S` to be a complete type and instead requires that `S` be the **name of a return type**.

From [`std::function`'s documentation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/func.wrap.func.general#1):

> The function class template provides polymorphic wrappers that generalize the notion of a function pointer. Wrappers can store, copy, and call arbitrary callable objects, **given a [call signature](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/func.def#def:call_signature)**, allowing functions to be first-class objects.

The above means that the template argument should be in the form of a **call signature**. From [call signature's documentation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/func.def#def:call_signature):

> A call signature is the **name of a return type followed by** a parenthesized comma-separated list of zero or more argument types.

(emphasis mine)

As we can see the above requires that `S` be the name of a return type. That is, it doesn't explicitly place any requirement on `S` being complete.

In other words, `S` in your given examples satisfies this [condition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/func.def#2) so that it is valid.